# Python subclass invoking method from parent class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, parent-child, subclass

I'm currently self-learning Python, and I came to the lesson about inheritance, so this is my first experience with subclasses. I'm learning from the book "Think Python", and the example is about creating classes that represent playing cards, decks, hands etc. The following example is copied from this book (with myself added method or two, as an exercise):

```
import random
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

class Card:
"""represents a standard playing card."""
    def __init__(self, suit=0, rank=2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    suit_names = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    rank_names = [None, 'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank], Card.suit_names[self.suit])

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        t1 = self.suit, self.rank
        t2 = other.suit, other.rank
        return cmp(t1, t2)

class Deck:
"""represents a standard deck of cards"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for card in self.cards:
            res.append(str(card))
        return '\n'.join(res)

    def pop_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add_card(self):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def sort(self):
        self.cards.sort(key=attrgetter('suit', 'rank'))

class Hand(Deck):
"""represents a hand of playing cards"""
    def __init__(self, label=''):
        self.cards = []
        self.label = label

    def move_cards(self, hand, num):
        for i in range(num):
            hand.add_card(self.pop_card())
```

My problem is with the Hand child class methods. If I try to invoke the move_cards method from the Hand child class, for example with `a = Deck()`, `b = Hand()`, trying to invoke `move_cards(b,2)`, or `a.move_cards(b,2)` gives me the same `AttributeError: 'Deck' object has no attribute 'move_cards'`.

Why is this happening or what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Your `a` object is still a `Deck` instance, so it doesn't know anything about the `move_cards` method. When using inheritance, the *subclass* inherits the behavior of the *superclass*, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`move_cards` is only defined for the subclass `Hand`, not the parent class `Deck`.

I think the order of inheritance is confusing in the example - `Hand` doesn't really feel like a subclass of `Deck`, rather they should both be subclasses of a common card collection (`Stack` say). For example (not tested):

```
class Stack:
"""represents a collection of cards"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        res = []
        for card in self.cards:
            res.append(str(card))
        return '\n'.join(res)

    def pop_card(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

    def add_card(self):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def sort(self):
        self.cards.sort(key=attrgetter('suit', 'rank'))

    def move_cards(self, dest, num):
        for i in range(num):
            dest.add_card(self.pop_card())

class Deck(Stack):
"""represents a deck of playing cards"""
    def __init__(self):
        Stack.__init__(self)
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

class Hand(Stack):
"""represents a hand of playing cards"""
    def __init__(self, label=''):
        Stack.__init__(self)
        self.label = label
```

Notice how the overrided constructors for the subclasses `Hand` and `Deck` call the parent constructor explicitly with `Stack.__init__(self)`. This initialises the `self.cards` member in the same way for each.

Comment: Thank you very much gentleman! I now see the error of my reading ways, it is clearly written in book that move_cards should be inside class Deck!

Comment: ...but now I'm getting "TypeError: add_card() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" (from my code example)

Comment: Your `add_card` method expects an argument called `card`. Change the definition to `add_card(self, card)` and call it with `a.add_card(c)`

Comment: Thank you for that advice! As for yours code, it fails when it needs to fill the deck with cards, initialization of `card = Card(suit, rank)` fails because of missing Card class.

Comment: Yes, I didn't bother including the Card class as it seemed to be fine as is. Just paste the original code for Card above my modified code.